# How does JUnit find tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I had assumed that JUnit found tests (inside classes derived from `junit.framework.TestCase`) by looking for methods annotated with `@Test`. However, I've included a test from http://256stuff.com/sources/jenkins_hash_java/JenkinsHashTest.java in a project. The structure of the code is as follows:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class JenkinsHashTest extends TestCase {
    public void testHashes() {
        ...//this code is run
    }   
}
```

I have confirmed that the test method `testHashes()` is run despite not being annotated with `@Test`. In case it's relevant, I'm invoking all of this via `gradle test`.

Comment: JUnit 4 uses the annotation `@Test`. JUnit 3 extends `TestCase` and runs all `testXXX` methods.

Comment: The relevant part is that you read about the differences between Junit 4 and 3. And that you then get rid of anything that has the Junit3 smell on it ( for example by reworking the extends relationship with @Test annotations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to this [Junit 3 vs Junit 4 Comparison](http://www.asjava.com/junit/junit-3-vs-junit-4-comparison/):

Basically, in JUnit 3 you need to extend `junit.framework.TestCase`. All test cases need to follow the `testXXX` pattern.

JUnit 4 removes that restrictions. Any public classes with a zero-argument public constructor can act as a test class. Any methods which need  consider as a test method should be annotated with the `@Test` annotation.

Comment: But how does JUnit 3 **find** those classes that extend `junit.framework.TestCase`. Reflection can't do it, because you need to know the name of the `package` that contains the test cases. How does JUnit4 **find** those methods? Reflection can't do it, because you need to know the name of the `package` that contains the classes that contain the method that contain the `@Test` annotation.

Comment: @IanBoyd it doesn’t. It’s up to the environment in which you embed JUnit, to provide that information.